# iOS JSON POST not accepted by php

Tags: php, ios, json

Unfortunately I have been searching for the fix (or reason) for 7 hours now and have finally conceded I need some help.

I have just started rewriting my application for ios (from android) and I am stuck with json in ios.

My JSON post Action;

```
      NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{'firstname':'%@' 'surname':'%@'      'yob':'%@' 'gender':'%@' 'hometown':'%@' 'phone':'%@' 'email':'%@' 'deviceid':'%@' 'regId':'%@'  'phonetype':'%@'}",[_FirstName text],[_Surname text],[_YOB text],[_Gender text],[_HomeTown text], [_PhoneNO text],[_Email text],[_deviceid text],[_regID text],[_phonetype text]];

  NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"***"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [request setValue:@"appplication/www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code:%d", [response statusCode]);

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)

    {

        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Respinse ==> %@", responseData);

        SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];

        NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];

        NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);

        NSInteger sucess = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"sucess"] integerValue];

        NSLog(@"%d",sucess);

        if (sucess==1)

        {

            NSLog(@"Signed up");

        }else {

            NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message@"];
       }
    }else {
       if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

and my php;

```
<?php


 include_once("../php/sign_up/connect_db.php");
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields/
if (!empty($_POST['firstname']) && !empty($_POST['surname']) && !empty($_POST['email']) &&     !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['hometown']) && !empty($_POST['deviceid']) && !empty($_POST['yob']) && !empty($_POST['regId']) && !empty($_POST['gender'])) {

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$hometown = $_POST['hometown'];
$deviceid = $_POST['deviceid'];
$phonetype = $_POST['phonetype'];
$yob = $_POST['yob'];
$regId = $_POST['regId'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

// include db connect class
//require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

   $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM User_signup WHERE (email = '".$email."')" ) or die(mysql_error());
 $existingemails = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if ($existingemails > 0) {

 $response["success"] = 0;
 $response["message"] = "Email address already exists";

 //echoing JSON response
 echo json_encode($response);

} 
else {



// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO User_signup(firstname, surname, email, phone, hometown, id, type, Yob, regid, gender) VALUES('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', '$phone', '$hometown', '$deviceid', '$phonetype', '$yob', '$regId', '$gender')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Thank you for signing up!";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "An Error has occurred, please try again later.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} 

   }else {
   // required field is missing
   $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Please check you have completed all required fields";

       // echoing JSON response
       echo json_encode($response);
      }

    ?>
```

And this is the JSON returned;

```
    2013-10-07 00:03:59.465 ***[2517:c07] PostData: {'firstname':'ouyb' 'surname':'ouy' 'yob':'vbouv' 'gender':'GENDERouvy' 'hometown':'ouvy' 'phone':'ou' 'email':'vy' 'deviceid':'ilbuyv' 'regId':'obyouovy' 'phonetype':'uby'}

2013-10-07 00:03:59.645 ***[2517:c07] Response code:200

2013-10-07 00:03:59.645 ***[2517:c07] Respinse ==> {"success":0,"message":"Please check you     have completed all required fields"}

2013-10-07 00:03:59.646 ***[2517:c07] {

message = "Please check you have completed all required fields";

success = 0;

}
```

Now my android app posts the json array in the same format and is accepted perfectly by the php. I cannot for the life of me work out what is wrong.

It would appear by removing the check "if empty" from php the php is called and run yet no data is entered into the database yet a new blank row is created. Which to me sounds like the app is not sending what it claims to send.

Any nudges in the correct direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON strings are enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes, and dictionary key/value pairs must be separated by a comma. See json.org for more information.

Note that there is a NSJSONSerialization class, which can create JSON data from a NSDictionary.

Comment: Hello thank you for the swift response. I cannot seem to include double quotes. At least they do not appear in the log of params sent. As for the comma is that in lieu of the colons?

Comment: @mark: No, the JSON has to look like `{"firstname":"ouyb","surname":"ouy", ...}`. But do have a look at NSJSONSerialization, that makes things easier. There are a lot of Q&A about NSJSONSerialization on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried that putting in @"{"firstname":"%@",...} but I get an error "Lexical or Preprocessor issue Expected ':'"  expecting me to replace the second " of firstname to a :  any ideas? I will start looking at NSJSONSerialization thank you for the hint.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://img2.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/18495/184956544c1b9ae387f6ef15cbd112e47bb84cc6.png). Can anyone see what it causing this? I have sucessfully used NSDictionary method but I need to know what went wrong last time :) Thank you again for the help @Martin R